# iPhone 5S broken screen root access without iTunes authorization

Tags: itunes, screen, iphone, root

I have an iPhone 5S with broken screen.
I need to save my photos to my PC/Mac; I can't authorize iTunes cause of course the screen is broken and I don't have iCloud, so the only way should be a root access, does anyone knows how to?

Answer (score 1):

#### Software

[iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) claims to grant you root access to iDevices without requiring a jailbreak:

> With iExplorer, you can access more files and folders without modifying (jailbreaking) your device than ever before. Need to access photos on your iPhone or iPod? Can do. Want to access the files and folders of your device's apps? Done. How about browsing through your iTunes backups? Check. What about the media folders containing your iTunes purchases? We've got that too. What about files in apps that are synced to iCloud? Yes, even that.*

[iBrowse](http://www.ibrowseapp.com/) is a simillar, free software by the same company, but it doesn't grant root access (which I'm not sure you need in order to access photos).

#### The "Windows" Method

From an answer on [Apple's support forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6352138?tstart=0):

> I plugged the phone into my Windows Computer and when it recognizes the phone is plugged in, a dialogue box pops up that asks if you want to import pictures and videos. You click import and it will pull everything off the phone and place it in a folder with the date as the name and put it in your pictures or my pictures folder. From there you can access the photos & videos!!

I'm not sure this works either, update in the comments so I can modify my answer.

#### Old Guide

I also found [a guide](https://www.iphonelife.com/tip/how-to-get-photos-off-iphone), written in 2008, and doesn't involve any 3rd party software: (Not sure it still works)

> 1. Connect your iPhone/iPod touch and launch Applications >Image Capture.
> 2. Go to Preferences >General.
> 3. Under Camera, select Image Capture in the “When a camera is connected, open:” option, and then click OK. Now when you connect your
>      iPhone/iPod touch, Image Capture will be launched and you can choose
>      where you want to download your images.

Comment: the problem is that both iexplorer and image capture need that the iphone has been authorized by itunes, but since the screen is broken i can´t press "authorize" on the screen

Comment: Do you have a passcode?

Comment: yes, but no touch id, i never used it

Comment: Do you have a Windows machine to try my suggested method with?

Comment: yes i tried, but to let the iphone appear as mass storage device i always have to authorize the computer, but of course i can´t cause the screen is broken

Answer (score -2):

Also had that issue, used linux to format, then used photorec on the empty "disk"